# Yet there is method in this Morse code

Tags: cipher

Sometimes a nonsense telegram
makes much more sense
after a methodical maneuver.
Here’s one for fun:

```
 - . -.. / ... .... . . - ... / ... . -. - / .... .. ... / .- -. - /
 - --- / - . . -. / ... .... . .. -.- / .. / ... .... .- -. - / .... . -..- /
 ... .. ... - . .-. / ... .- .-.. / .- ... / ... .... . / .. ... ... ..- . -.. /
 ..-. . . / ... .... .. ..-. - / .. ... / .-- . - / ... ..- . - /
 . ...- . .-. / - .. -. / ... ..- .. - / . . -.- / ... .. .-. . -.

 TED SHEETS SENT HIS ANT
 TO TEEN SHEIK I SHANT HEX
 SISTER SAL AS SHE ISSUED
 FEE SHIFT IS WET SUET
 EVER TIN SUIT EEK SIREN

 20 5 4 0 19 8 5 5 20 19 0 19 5 14 20 0 8 9 19 0 1 14 20 0
 20 15 0 20 5 5 14 0 19 8 5 9 11 0 9 0 19 8 1 14 20 0 8 5 24 0
 19 9 19 20 5 18 0 19 1 12 0 1 19 0 19 8 5 0 9 19 19 21 5 4 0
 6 5 5 0 19 8 9 6 20 0 9 19 0 23 5 20 0 19 21 5 20 0
 5 22 5 18 0 20 9 14 0 19 21 9 20 0 5 5 11 0 19 9 18 5 14

 10100 101 100 0 10011 1000 101 101 10100 10011 0 10011 101 1110 10100 0 1000 1001 10011 0 1 1110 10100 0
 10100 1111 0 10100 101 101 1110 0 10011 1000 101 1001 1011 0 1001 0 10011 1000 1 1110 10100 0 1000 101 11000 0
 10011 1001 10011 10100 101 10010 0 10011 1 1100 0 1 10011 0 10011 1000 101 0 1001 10011 10011 10101 101 100 0
 110 101 101 0 10011 1000 1001 110 10100 0 1001 10011 0 10111 101 10100 0 10011 10101 101 10100 0
 101 10110 101 10010 0 10100 1001 1110 0 10011 10101 1001 10100 0 101 101 1011 0 10011 1001 10010 101 1110
```

**What’s that telegram really trying to tell?**

Everything you need to know is below
and most of the work to be done is above.

```
     Morse     Binary           Morse      Binary            Morse      Binary

    A  .-     1      1         J  .---   10    1010         S  ...    19   10011
    B  -...   2     10         K  -.-    11    1011         T  -      20   10100
    C  -.-.   3     11         L  .-..   12    1100         U  ..-    21   10101
    D  -..    4    100         M  --     13    1101         V  ...-   22   10110
    E  .      5    101         N  -.     14    1110         W  .--    23   10111
    F  ..-.   6    110         O  ---    15    1111         X  -..-   24   11000
    G  --.    7    111         P  .--.   16   10000         Y  -.--   25   11001
    H  ....   8   1000         Q  --.-   17   10001         Z  --..   26   11010
    I  ..     9   1001         R  .-.    18   10010      space         0     0
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the Morse, plain text, letter-numbers, and binary do actually match one another?

Comment: All 4 transcriptions are meant to match completely (and have been proofread from many angles)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can see how David Thomas got [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50639/18250) as I worked it out and got the same answer, but as he hasn't added an explanation (he has now), this is how you get the answer:

The telegram is telling you

> **THE MORE MIRTH THE MERRIER**

**TL;DR**

> The morse code gives binary for the phrase

## **Detailed Explanation**

The morse code represents binary, each dash is a 1 and each dot is a 0.

Converting gives:

> 1 0 100 / 000 0000 0 0 1 000 / 000 0 10 1 / 0000 00 000 / 01 10 1 /
> 1 111 / 1 0 0 10 / 000 0000 0 00 101 / 00 / 000 0000 01 10 1 / 0000 0 1001 /
> 000 00 000 1 0 010 / 000 01 0100 / 01 000 / 000 0000 0 / 00 000 000 001 0 100 /
> 0010 0 0 / 000 0000 00 0010 1 / 00 000 / 011 0 1 / 000 001 0 1 /
> 0 0001 0 010 / 1 00 10 / 000 001 00 1 / 0 0 101 / 000 00 010 0 10

Squishing that together gives:

> 10100 / 0000000001000 / 0000101 / 000000000 / 01101 /
> 1111 / 10010 / 0000000000101 / 00 / 000000001101 / 000001001 /
> 0000000010010 / 000010100 / 01000 / 00000000 / 000000000010100 /
> 001000 / 00000000000101 / 00000 / 01101 / 00000101 /
> 000010010 / 10010 / 000001001 / 00101 / 00000010010

Removing the slashes and leading zeroes, and also for any word which is comprised of only 0s, replacing it with a / to make it easier to read gives:

> 10100 1000 101 / 1101 1111 10010 101 / 1101 1001 10010 10100 1000 / 10100 100 101 / 1101 101 10010 10010 1001 101 10010

Now converting from binary using the table, and the / as a space gives the final phrase:

> THE MORE MIRTH THE MERRIER

**Red Herrings**

The red herring that threw me and Gareth in chat off to start:

> There are 26 words in the question, which we thought might correspond to the alphabet.

And another red herring which initially convinced Gareth to post an answer is that

> The first part of the morse is -.-.. which matches the first piece of binary 10100, however this doesn't work for all the parts.

But the biggest red herring:

> Everything in the telegram but the morse code is unneeded!

Comment: The other red herring that really threw me off: the first "letter" of the binary is 10100 and the first *word* of the Morse is -.-.. !

Comment: I think you meant to write "26 characters" not words

Comment: No, 26 *words* in the original text.

Comment: Ah, well the answer has 26 *characters* :P

Comment: Great comprehensive answer, Beastly Gerbil. Yes this was an experiment in red-herrings:actual-effort-required ratio, with the all-but-solved puzzle even beginning with a combination hint and red herring.

Comment: @humn you could actually have taken this a step further, and have 'the more mirth the merrier' equal 10010 (tmmtm) and have something to do with an 'r'

Answer (score 7):

Looks to me like  ...

> "the more mirth the merrier": with '-'=1 and '.'=0, there is one binary letter per word (with lots of distracting leading zeros), spelling out this phrase.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Please could you add an explanantion?