# Lined to the nines

Tags: mathematics, pattern, formation-of-numbers

Each line in the following list of equalities may be made true
by moving, according to a common rule,
the numbers at the left of the `=` equals sign in that line.


     
**What is the value of `X` in `X 11 10 9 = 11`?**

```
                        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  =  0
                          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  =  1
                            2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  =  2
                              3 4 5 6 7 8 9  =  3
                                4 5 6 7 8 9  =  4
                                  5 6 7 8 9  =  5
                                    6 7 8 9  =  6
                                      7 8 9  =  7
                                        8 9  =  8
                                       10 9  =  9
                                    11 10 9  =  10
                                  X 11 10 9  =  11
                                 12 11 10 9  =  12
                           10 11 12 11 10 9  =  13
                                             .
                                             .
                                             .
              ... including, in case it’s not obvious, ...
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9  =  153
                                             .
                                             .
                                             .
```

*No symbols or markings need to be added
and the numbers may move left, right, up and down
as long as they remain whole, separate,
and to the left of the* `=` *equals sign.*

The rule for moving numbers is so simple that
it can be stated in an English sentence of 9 words or fewer.
Understanding the result, though, requires remembering
a convention familiar to a vast majority of mathematicians
and taught to even more students who do not go on to pursue that field.

This list of lines begins with `= 0` but has no end
and, incidentally, the entry for each line has infinitely many alternatives.
The present equations were chosen to emphasize some patterns
into which the value for **`X`** fits in a surprising way.

<sub>(Note: This puzzle’s presentation was overhauled in April, 2020,
       and many comments from 2017 no longer apply exactly.)</sub>

Comment: Does "to a unique integer result" mean (1) that each line's result is well-defined or (2) that all the lines' results are different?

Comment: Thanks once again, @Gareth, edited.  I was trying to avert unintended utterly simple solutions, like every line = C.

Comment: I was looking for an 'x' in the first line (line 1). It's actually lower-case 'L'.

Comment: Sorry about that, @Lawrence, thank you for the clarification! I dithered between uppercase and lowercase for the sakes of aesthetics and clarity. Didn't want anyone looking for line X. Originally the lines were numbered.

Comment: @humn No problem :) . Upper-case line references is a good idea in this question, actually.

Comment: Column? Not rows? And can this pattern continue infinitely? If no, what is the end of it?

Comment: It does continue infinitely _forward_, not backward,  @William Nathanael, but if you saw more it would be easier. Another mention (hint?) for the next edit.

Comment: I assume x=12? Column values R to L (9-9=0, 10-8=2, 11-7=4, 12-6=6)? not sure this one fit or not? It just a wild guess :p

Comment: `to a well-defined unique-from-each-other integer result.` does that mean it can't be 12? Because the `line m` would be equal to `line l` or I missunderstood that?

Comment: You are on the right track, @Paul Karam, yet part of the challenge is to define that track. (No it's not 12, but close.)

Comment: Yeah I am trying to. It's so simple that it feels so hard.. hehe

Comment: Thank you for a great puzzle idea or two, @Paul Karam! Something to seem so simple that it's almost impossible.

Comment: This puzzle also makes an implicit request for the simple column of numbers that result from evaluating the lines. A forthcoming edit will make this explicit.

Comment: So to clarify: the goal is to find 1) a variadic function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ and 2) a sequence $a_i$, given a set of arguments $X_i$ such that $f(X_i)=a_i$?

Comment: [amended] Great way to formalize it, @2012rcampion, yes. And $f$ looks trivial (and actually is fairly simple) while $a_i$ is truly simple and looks it. Also, the order of arguments to $f$ does matter, even though the puzzle calls those numbers a "set."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composition is

> A string of right-associative $x_y$ operations, where $y$ is the base to which $x$ is expressed. The RHS is expressed in base 10 (the familiar '10', as opposed to the one where 'every base is base 10' :) ).

With an ascending string of single-digit numbers, the whole string reduces to the left-most operand because we start on the right and each pair reduces to the left operand. For example,

> $3_4 = 3$.

The given examples all check out, including the monster that evaluates to 153.

We can start with [12 11 10 9] = 12, as given, then continue with:

> $13_{12}$ = 12 + 3 = 15
>  $14_{15}$ = 15 + 4 = 19
>  ...
>  $10_{153}$ = 153

Now, we have the following reduction since [11 10 9] = 10:

> $X_{[11,10,9]} = X_{10}$

which we are told evaluates to 11.

Therefore $X=11$.

> $$ \require{begingroup}\begingroup \def\b#1{_{\large\,#1}} \begin{array}{rcl}                   0\b{1\b{2\b{3\b{4\b{5\b{6\b{7\b{8\b9}}}}}}}} & = & 0  \\                       1\b{2\b{3\b{4\b{5\b{6\b{7\b{8\b9}}}}}}}  & = & 1  \\                           2\b{3\b{4\b{5\b{6\b{7\b{8\b9}}}}}}   & = & 2  \\                               3\b{4\b{5\b{6\b{7\b{8\b9}}}}}    & = & 3  \\                                   4\b{5\b{6\b{7\b{8\b9}}}}     & = & 4  \\                                       5\b{6\b{7\b{8\b9}}}      & = & 5  \\                                           6\b{7\b{8\b9}}       & = & 6  \\                                               7\b{8\b9}        & = & 7  \\                                                   8\b9         & = & 8  \\                                                  10\b9         & = & 9  \\                                             11\b{10\b9}        & = & 10 \\                            {\large\bf 11}\b{11\b{10\b9}}       & = & 11 \\                                        12\b{11\b{10\b9}}       & = & 12 \\                              10\b{11\b{12\b{11\b{10\b9}}}}     & = & 13 \\                                                                & \vdots \\  10\b{11\b{12\b{13\b{14\b{15\b{16\b{17\b{18\rlap{\b{19\b{20\b{19\b{18\b{17\b{16\b{15\b{14\b{13\b{12\b{11\b{10\b9}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}                                                                & = & 153 \\                                                                & \vdots  \\ \end{array} \endgroup $$

Comment: One for the road. :)

Comment: And a picture as a chaser

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The puzzle’s presentation has been revised since the time of
         this posting. The version from that time is appended to this answer.**

---

Lines $i$ and $j$ are the only other pair presented where consecutive rows have the same number of elements. There, the left-most digit is incremented by 2. Otherwise, the number in each column stays the same as the preceding row, except that new numbers can be introduced to the left. The *rules* for the new numbers isn't sought by this puzzle, and $x$ can be determined by the simple rule observed for lines $i$ and $j$.

Applying that simple rule to lines $l$ and $m$,

> the increment-by-two rule gives us $12 = m + 2$, so $m = 10$.

---

#### Version of the puzzle when this answer was posted

Each of the following `line a` through `line n` evaluates,
by one utterly simple secret rule,
to a well-defined unique-from-each-other integer result.
The resulting column of integers has an equally simple pattern.

```
line a:                         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line b:                           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line c:                             2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line d:                               3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line e:                                 4 5 6 7 8 9
line f:                                   5 6 7 8 9
line g:                                     6 7 8 9
line h:                                       7 8 9
line i:                                         8 9
line j:                                        10 9
line k:                                     11 10 9
line l:                                   X 11 10 9
line m:                                  12 11 10 9
line n:                            10 11 12 11 10 9
```

> **What is the value of `X` in `line l`?**
>
> (And what utterly simple rule applies to all lines?)

Notes from comments:

The `l` in `line l` is lowercase L, not numbercase one.

This sequence continues forward infinitely but not backward.

Comment: Thank you for following one of my false leads. I'm trying to learn how to balance genuine clues and red herrings. [Another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50636/yet-there-is-method-in-this-morse-code) was nothing but herrings.

Comment: Apologies, Lawrence, I neglected to acknowledge that your rule does work, yet an even simpler rule produced these lines

Comment: @humn That's ok. I'll make another attempt.

Comment: [amended, previous comment]
Apologies, Lawrence, I neglected to acknowledge that your rule does work.
And you're right, a rule for new numbers is not sought!
Yet an even simpler rule than present _evaluates_
(not _produced_, as misstated in the previous comment, sorry!)
these lines, as you already understood
but might've formed doubts from that comment.
I'm also adding to the puzzle statement
an explicit request for the resulting column of numbers.
(Also working on a hint.)

Comment: In fact every line can be represented infinitely many ways with the same resulting column of evaluations, but the way `line l` is constructed, only one value of `X` works.

Comment: With your clarifications in the main question and the new column of uppercase variables to the right, I'm now not sure that the question is sufficiently defined. If *all* the outputs (the uppercase letters) are undefined, it comes down to a pure guess as to what the function from the 'lines' to the uppercase letters should be.

Comment: So, for example, the trivial function f(line) = 0 fits all the facts (with $A=B= ... =0$), and it doesn't matter what X is.

Comment: Which is why I specified unique-from-each-other. That sentence and the next will be combined to be clearer in the next edit, thanks to your making me see that! I've been working on making this puzzle less mysterious in other ways too.

Comment: @humn I don't think the current question wording rules out 'all zero', but the bigger issue is that it doesn't constrain (at all) the mapping from the list of numbers to the uppercase letters. That means there's no way to factor in the relevance of the (LHS) lists. For example, I could set A=1, B=2, C=3, etc, ignoring the LHS altogether but still fulfilling all the requirements about the RHS.

Comment: (Too pooped to have this moved to chat, moderators.) (Almost too pooped to finish the current insufficient edit, Lawrence.) Each RHS still must be produced by a single simple-looking rule from its LHS. (I thrive on feedback, in any case. In another world I'm an editor with separation anxiety whenever anything gets away to final press.)

Comment: @humn Ok, I'll accept that the question isn't (directly) about the uppercase letters, so that gets a pass. :)

Comment: Thank you for attending this puzzle early on, @Lawrence!  I'm sure you know that each bounty takes a day or so to ripen before it can be picked.

Comment: @humn I’m glad I did. I had about a 17h day today if I’ve counted my hours correctly, and this is such a nice surprise to find as I’m unwinding from the long day. Thanks again, and have a happy Easter. :)

Comment: @humm Wow, this was a bonus - I hadn’t expected so much bounty. Thank you for your message the other day, by the way. I had a nice, long rest.

Comment: Perhaps solving this puzzle was a nice palate cleanser for you, @Lawrence, and when I say that an answer gets a bounty, it gets its _own_ bounty.  It's the principle, not the points.  Again, I am grateful for your helping me realize that the original presentation was too coyly ambiguous.  What if I append a snapshot to the solution, as I did to your previous answers, but this time of the rearranged numbers to go along with your more-complete-than-I'd-hoped analysis?

Comment: @humn Solving the years-long puzzle was certainly satisfying. Feel free to edit as you wish. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The puzzle’s presentation has been revised since the time of
         this posting. The version from that time is appended to this answer.**

---

> Rule: adjacent elements on each line differ by 1.

The only element adjacent to $x$ is 11. So if $x \ne 12$ by line $m$, we have $x=10$.

---

#### Version of the puzzle when this answer was posted

Each of the following `line a` through `line n` evaluates,
by one utterly simple secret rule,
to a well-defined unique-from-each-other integer result.
The resulting column of integers has an equally simple pattern.

```
line a:                         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line b:                           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line c:                             2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line d:                               3 4 5 6 7 8 9
line e:                                 4 5 6 7 8 9
line f:                                   5 6 7 8 9
line g:                                     6 7 8 9
line h:                                       7 8 9
line i:                                         8 9
line j:                                        10 9
line k:                                     11 10 9
line l:                                   X 11 10 9
line m:                                  12 11 10 9
line n:                            10 11 12 11 10 9
```

> **What is the value of `X` in `line l`?**
>
> (And what utterly simple rule applies to all lines?)

Notes from comments:

The `l` in `line l` is lowercase L, not numbercase one.

This sequence continues forward infinitely but not backward.

Comment: But that was "backward" I think, which OP said that it doesn't work like that... I suppose.

Comment: I like it! That adjacent elements differ by 1 was an aesthetic choice, though.

Comment: The puzzle statement has been clarified and hinted, but I realized that I've never seen the simple-looking mathematics in play be used like this, entirely valid though it is.